# nullpointerexception declaring a listview

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

i am declaring a listiview and this return me a nullpointerexception but i don't know why:

This is de xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar">
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_home"
            android:src="@drawable/title_home"
            android:onClick="onClickHome" />

        <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />
        <TextView style="@style/TitleBarText" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView  
    android:id="@+id/ListaLugares"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>



    </LinearLayout>
```

And the next is the code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.listatab);
    context = getBaseContext();

    ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaLugares);

    l.setAdapter(new miAdapter(this));



  }
```

its to simple but i don't know the error, in XML i must to name listalugares to the list view because i will use a custom BaseAdapter

Comment: You're getting a null pointer exception because `findViewById()` can't find the `R.id.ListaLugares`. Is that the full XML?

Comment: yes this is the full listatab.xml

Comment: Ok, sorry, now works fine, i don't now why..

Answer (score 0):

Every element in a layout needs `layout_width` and `layout_height`. That must be it.